# REPL for Typescript with application loaded

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

How can I get a REPL for a project generated using create-react-app with the Typescript flag?

I've installed ts-node which runs but does not seem to include the code in the project.  Is there a command using that or something else that will get me a REPL with my application preloaded?  Looking for something equivalent to rails console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but its not hard to wire up yourself. The difference from the rails console is that in ruby everything is more or less global, or accessible from something global. But in JS, you import specific things from specific files, so many functions/classes could have identical names.

This all means that you must decide what code from your application is available to the console by default.

---

You want [`node:repl` from the node standard library.](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html)

Make file called `console.log` somewhere.

```
import * as repl from 'node:repl';

const replServer = repl.start('> ')
replServer.context.thingYouWantToBeLocal = { abc: 123 };
```

Add a script to your `package.json`:

```
"console": "ts-node ./console.ts"
```

And then:

```
npm run console
```

Which should pop up a prompt. And if you type:

```
console.log(thingYouWantToBeLocal)
```

Then you should get back

```
{ abc: 123 }
```